# How i can use Protobuffer using a tcp connection?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, tcp, protobuf-java

I want so send protobuffer to a server which do something with the protobuffer, im developing on android studio.

```
private OutputStream toServer ;  

public void serialize(byte[]message) throws IOException {
  try{
           toServer= new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));
           toServer.write(message);
           toServer.write(message,0,message.length);

           toServer.flush();
}
  catch (java.net.SocketException e){     
  e.printStackTrace();
       }
```

Comment: if server expects to get plain protobuff message the,  yes ... using `ObjectOutputStream` when serverside is not using java is bad(and redundant as `BufferedOutputStream` has already write method)

Comment: A simple google search "how can i use protobuf over tcp" got me several tutorials.